# Logstash settup to Mysql hosted on AWS RDS. Won't connect

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-rds

I have a MySQL DB hosted on AWS RDS. I am running ElasticSearch locally and using Logstash to retrieve data from MYSQL server that is on AWS to then push the data to my ElasticSearch DB.

The problem is that my logstash file isn't settup correctly I guess:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://aws.ffffffffff.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/dbName?user=userName&password=pword"
        jdbc_user => "user"
        jdbc_password => "pword"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector J 8.0\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from data-5"
        type => "data-5"
        tags => ["data-5"]
    }

    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://aws.ffffffffff.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/dbName?user=userName&password=pword"
        jdbc_user => "user"
        jdbc_password => "pword"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector J 8.0\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from data-4"
        type => "data-4"
        tags => ["data-4"]
    }

    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://aws.ffffffffff.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/dbName?user=userName&password=pword"
        jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "pword"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector J 8.0\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from data-3"
        type => "data-3"
        tags => ["data-3"]
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }

    if "data-5" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["http://127.0.0.1:9200/"]
            index => "data-5"
            document_type => "data-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }

    if "data-4" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["http://127.0.0.1:9200/"]
            index => "data-4"
            document_type => "data-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }

    if "data-3" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["http://127.0.0.1:9200/"]
            index => "data-3"
            document_type => "data-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the fun part of programming right?

Anyway, locally I am on windows as you may be able to tell from the file path to the jdbc driver library. My jdbc connection to the AWS RDS is copied and pasted from AWS Console, so no typos were involved.

I am told that I only need to append **jdbc:mysql://** to the url. But is there anything I'm missing to do in the AWS console? Do I need to modify my RDS instance?

The error by the way is:

```
 Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times 
{:error_message=>"Java::ComMysqlCjJdbcExceptions::CommunicationsException: 
Communications link failure\n\n
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. 
The driver has not received any packets from the server."
```

Comment: This problem is very similar to this SO post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209686/logstash-unable-to-connect-to-external-amazon-rds-database

Comment: To also add, yes I have no problem connecting to the RDS locally through my terminal, or through my node.js server.

Comment: Could this be a problem with AWS? Could it just be because elastic search and logstash are being ran locally and not AWS so the connection is being refused?

Comment: I saw a post where someone mentioend MariaDB has less issues than MySQL for logstash. I may try that out. Although I'd realllllyyy hate to change databases for one problem.

Comment: I will most likely first host logstash and elastic search on AWS before I switch over to MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and SSL was not enabled for communication. So, AWS RDS was not allowing to connect.

I specified an additional query param `useSSL=false` to JDBC connection string, and problem was solved.

So, in your case, the `jdbc_connection_string` would be as follows:

```
"jdbc:mysql://aws.ffffffffff.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/dbName?useSSL=false&user=userName&password=pword"
```

Comment: Thanks, this may help someone else. My actual problem was that MySQL on RDS wasn't up to date. I was using 6 instead of 8.* or whatever the latest is.